# How to calculate surface states in Weyl semimetals?

Tags: hamiltonian, dirac-equation, topological-insulators, tight-binding, weyl-semimetal

I'm reading an article https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.89.235127. Fig. 2 in this article shows band structures calculated from Eq. (9), (13), (14), (15), and (16). For example, Eq. (9) is given by
$$
H_1 = \tau_x \left( \sigma_z \sin k_y + v \right) + \tau_y \sin k_x + \tau_z \left( M - \cos k_x - \cos k_y - \cos k_z \right)
$$
Such Hamiltonians are $4 \times 4$ matrices, but each band structures in Fig. 2 have more than four bands because they are about a finite number of cells along $x$-directions.

My questions is how to consider peridic boundary conditions and how to calculate the band sturcutres like Fig. 2 from the above $4 \times 4$ matrices. I want plot Fig. 2. I'm looking for literatures but I couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done by breaking periodic translation in one of the directions (here they keep translational invariance in the $k_y,k_z$ direction but break it in the $k_x$ direction). Thinks of this as a stack of $L$ layers in the x-direction, each of which is periodic in $y,z$.

There are two traditional approaches to this: Surface Greens functions, which approximate your system by a semi-infinite slab (e.g. $x\in [0,\infty)$) or slab calculations (e.g. $x\in [0,L]$ for some large $L$).

I will provide a full explanation for the slab method, for the case of a square lattice with all orbitals located at the origin.

Essentially, you need to take the inverse Fourier transform of your tight-binding model with respect to the $k_x$ variable only. In general your Hamiltonian is given by (where $\alpha,\beta$ are orbital/spin indices):
$$
\hat{H}_{\alpha \beta} = \sum_{k_x,k_y,k_z}H_{\alpha \beta}(k_x,k_y,k_z)c^{\dagger}_{\alpha}(k_x,k_y,k_z)c_{\beta}(k_x,k_y,k_z)
$$
Now Fourier transform *only* the $k_x$-component as:

$$
c^{\dagger}_{\alpha}(k_x,k_y,k_z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\sum_{x}c^{\dagger}_{x,k_y,k_z}
$$

So that:

$$
\hat{H}_{\alpha \beta} = \frac{1}{L}\sum_{k_y, k_z}\sum_{k_x}\sum_{x,x'} H_{\alpha \beta}(k_x,k_y,k_z)c^{\dagger}_{\alpha}(x,k_y,k_z)c_{\beta}(x',k_y,k_z)e^{ik_x(x-x')}
$$

So what does this look like in your case? Let me focus just on Eq.9, which is given by:
$$
H_1(k_x,k_y,k_z) = \tau_x(\sigma_z\sin k_y +v) + \tau_y\sin k_x+\tau_z(M-\cos k_x - \cos k_y -\cos k_z)
$$

Which in matrix form looks like:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
M-\cos k_x-\cos k_y-\cos k_z & 0 & (\sin k_y-i\sin k_x)+v & 0 \\
0 & M-\cos k_x-\cos k_y-\cos k_z & 0 & (-\sin k_y-i\sin k_x)+v \\
(\sin k_y+i\sin k_x)+v & 0 & -M+\cos k_x+\cos k_y+\cos k_z & 0 \\
0 & (-\sin k_y+i\sin k_x)+v & 0 & -M+\cos k_x+\cos k_y+\cos k_z 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let's focus on the diagonal onsite term $M$ first:

$$
\hat{H}^M_{\alpha \alpha} = \frac{M}{L}\sum_{k_y, k_z}\sum_{k_x}\sum_{x,x'} c^{\dagger}_{\alpha}(x,k_y,k_z)c_{\beta}(x',k_y,k_z)e^{ik_x(x-x')}
$$
$$
= M\sum_{k_x,k_y}\sum_x c^{\dagger}_{\alpha}(x,k_y,k_z)c_{\alpha}(x,k_y,k_z)
$$

Where I have used that:
$$
\frac{1}{L}\sum_{x,x'}\sum_{k_x}e^{ik_x(x-x')} A(x,x') = \sum_{x,x'}\delta_{x,x'}A(x,x') = \sum_{x}A(x,x)
$$

The same clearly holds true for all terms that do not involve $k_x$. Finally, for the terms that *do* involve $k_x$, use that:

$$
\frac{1}{L}\sum_{x,x'}\sum_{k_x}e^{ik_x(x-x')} \cos(k_x) A(x,x') = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{L}\sum_{x,x'}\sum_{k_x}e^{ik_x(x-x')} (e^{ik_x}+e^{-ik_x}) A(x,x') 
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{x,x'}(\delta_{x,x'+1}+\delta_{x,x'-1})A(x,x') = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{x}(A(x,x+1)+A(x,x-1))
$$

And similarly:
$$
\frac{1}{L}\sum_{x,x'}\sum_{k_x}e^{ik_x(x-x')} \sin(k_x) A(x,x') = \frac{1}{2i}\frac{1}{L}\sum_{x,x'}\sum_{k_x}e^{ik_x(x-x')} (e^{ik_x}-e^{-ik_x}) A(x,x') 
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{x,x'}(\delta_{x,x'+1}-\delta_{x,x'-1})A(x,x') = \frac{1}{2i}\sum_{x}(A(x,x+1)-A(x,x-1))
$$

Thus, we learn that $\cos(k_x)$ corresponds to hoppings from unit cell $x$ to $x+1$ that are equal in the forward/backward direction (assuming a square lattice) and $\sin(k_x)$ corresponds to the same hoppings that are *different* in the forward/backward directions (with an additional factor of $i$).

Now the general idea is to build a matrix $H^{fin}_{\alpha \beta xx'}$, labelled by orbitals $\alpha,\beta \in [1,4]$ and the position $x,x' \in [0,L]$ for some $L^1$. Thus, we go from a Hamiltonian having $4$ eigenvalues, to a Hamiltonian having $4L$ eigenvalues.

Whilst it is straightforward to construct this by hand, much of this is also implemented in various packages, where I recommend the [$\texttt{PythTb}$ package](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/pythtb/index.html). This package works by specifying *all* hoppings in real-space, and then breaking periodicity in a specified direction. Using the code below, I get the following plots:

[image: BHZ surface plot]

Which look awfully similar to Fig.2 a), except that I have twice the number of surface states for $k_z = 0.3\pi$. This is because I have plotted the surface states from *both* surfaces, whereas they only plot the states on one surface. There is functionality in $\texttt{PythTB}$ for checking where the states localize, and this can be used to remove the other surface state if desired.

I leave the rest of Fig.2 for you to plot.

$^1$  Note that, because the hoppings are only between $x$ and $x\pm 1$, this matrix will only be nonzero in a band of width $1$ around the diagonal in $(x,x')$ space.

Code to generate figure:

```
from pythtb import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos,sin,pi

def H_k(k,M,v):
    kx = 2*pi*k[0]
    ky = 2*pi*k[1]
    kz = 2*pi*k[2]
    H = np.zeros((4,4),dtype=np.complex128)
    H[0,0] = M-cos(kx)-cos(ky)-cos(kz)
    H[1,1] = H[0,0]
    H[2,2] = -H[0,0]
    H[3,3] = -H[0,0]
    H[0,2] = sin(ky)-1j*sin(kx)+v
    H[2,0] = np.conjugate(H[0,2])
    H[1,3] = -sin(ky)-1j*sin(kx)+v
    H[3,1] = np.conjugate(H[1,3])
    return H

# lattice vectors and orbital positions
lat=[[1.0, 0.0,0.0], [0.0,1.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,1.0]]
orb=[[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0]]

# 3D tight-binding model
BHZ=tb_model(3, 3, lat, orb)

#Parameters from paper
v = 0.5
M = 2
kz_vals = [0.3/2.0, 0.5/2.0,0.7/2.0] #Defined as fraction of 2pi
L = 10
debug = False

# define hopping between orbitals
# Notation:
# (Hopping strength, alpha, beta, x-x')

#M
BHZ.set_onsite([M,M,-M,-M]) 

#V
BHZ.set_hop(v, 0,2,[0,0,0]) 
BHZ.set_hop(v, 1,3,[0,0,0]) 


#cos k_x on diagonal
BHZ.set_hop(-1/2.0, 0,0,[1,0,0]) 
BHZ.set_hop(-1/2.0, 1,1,[1,0,0]) 
BHZ.set_hop(1/2.0, 2,2,[1,0,0]) 
BHZ.set_hop(1/2.0, 3,3,[1,0,0]) 

#cos k_y on diagonal
BHZ.set_hop(-1/2.0, 0,0,[0,1,0]) 
BHZ.set_hop(-1/2.0, 1,1,[0,1,0]) 
BHZ.set_hop(1/2.0, 2,2,[0,1,0]) 
BHZ.set_hop(1/2.0, 3,3,[0,1,0]) 

#cos k_z on diagonal
BHZ.set_hop(-1/2.0, 0,0,[0,0,1]) 
BHZ.set_hop(-1/2.0, 1,1,[0,0,1]) 
BHZ.set_hop(1/2.0, 2,2,[0,0,1]) 
BHZ.set_hop(1/2.0, 3,3,[0,0,1]) 

#sin k_y off-diagonal
BHZ.set_hop(1/(2.0*1j), 0,2,[0,1,0]) 
BHZ.set_hop(-1/(2.0*1j), 0,2,[0,-1,0]) 
BHZ.set_hop(-1/(2.0*1j), 1,3,[0,1,0]) 
BHZ.set_hop(1/(2.0*1j), 1,3,[0,-1,0]) 

#sin k_x off-diagonal
BHZ.set_hop(-1/2.0, 0,2,[1,0,0]) 
BHZ.set_hop(1/2.0, 0,2,[-1,0,0])
BHZ.set_hop(-1/2.0, 1,3,[1,0,0]) 
BHZ.set_hop(1/2.0, 1,3,[-1,0,0]) 
 
BHZ_finite = BHZ.cut_piece(L,0) #Cut along x
if debug: #Check that hoppings are correct (optional)
    diff = 0
    for kx in np.linspace(0,1,10):
        for ky in np.linspace(0,1,10):
            for kz in np.linspace(0,1,10):
                pythtb_Ham = BHZ._gen_ham([kx,ky,kz])
                my_Ham = H_k([kx,ky,kz],M,v)
                diff += np.sum(np.abs(pythtb_Ham-my_Ham))
    if np.abs(diff) > 1e-10:
        raise ValueError("H is not corrctly reproduced!")


fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols = 3,figsize=(12,4))
for i_kz, kz in enumerate(kz_vals):
# solve along ky for fixed kz
    k=[[-0.5, kz],[0.5,kz]]
    (k_vec,k_dist,k_node)=BHZ_finite.k_path(k, 100,report=False)
    evals=BHZ_finite.solve_all(k_vec)

    # plot bandstructure



    for current_E in range(evals.shape[0]):
        ax[i_kz].plot(k_dist,evals[current_E,:],color="black")

    ax[i_kz].axhline(0)
    ax[i_kz].set_xlabel(r"$k_y$")
    ax[i_kz].set_ylabel("Energy")
    ax[i_kz].set_xlim(k_node[0],k_node[-1])
    ax[i_kz].set_xticks([k_node[0], k_node[-1]])
    ax[i_kz].set_xticklabels([r"-$\pi$", r"$\pi$"])
    ax[i_kz].set_title(r"$k_z = $ %.2f $\pi$" %(2*kz))
    ax[i_kz].set_ylim(-3,3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Wow! I started to understand the paper thanks to your derivations! I really thank you! :)